# Getting hot reload to work in a codesandbox node environment

Tags: codesandbox

I've created a codesandbox project that runs both frontend and backend using `concurrently` - it all works great, but I can't get `react-scripts` hot reload functionality to work.
That means that every time I change my `tsx` file - I need to manually reload the page to reflect these changes.

Here's my codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/remult-react-todo-4ztjw?file=/src/App.tsx

In the browser console I see many errors saying:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('<URL>') does not match the recipient window's origin ('<URL>').

WebSocket connection to 'wss://4ztjw-3000.sse.codesandbox.io:3000/ws' failed:
```